# Rust: Is there a way to convert BufReader<File> to a String?

Tags: rust

I'm working on a .obj reader in Rust, and I've run into a bit of an issue. The only way I've found you are able to read a file is through "BufReader", though I can't seem to be able to convert that to a String for further processing. Here's my code so far:

```
let input: BufReader<File> = BufReader::new(File::open("cube.obj").expect("didn't work"));
    let model: Obj = Obj::load(input);
    let s: String = input.chars()
    .map(|x| x.ok().unwrap())
    .take_while(|&x| x != ' ')
    .collect();

    println!("input: {}", input);
```

If anybody more experienced with rust knows what I could do, it would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `BufRead` implements `Read`, which means you can use [read_to_string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string), or any other more appropriate method from that trait.

Comment: You don't need to wrap in a `BufReader` if you want to read the whole file into memory. You can call `read_to_string` on the `File` struct itself. An even shorter way is to use `std::fs::read_to_string`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to import the trait `std::io::Read` and then can call `Read::read_to_string` to read the content of the file.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, Read};

fn main() {
    let mut input: BufReader<File> = BufReader::new(File::open("cube.obj").expect("didn't work"));
    let mut str = String::new();
    input.read_to_string(&mut str).expect("cannot read string");
    println!("input: {}", str);
}
```

Comment: `use std::io::{self, Read};` seems to be enough to complete that task, no need to explicitly type `BufReader` as well (Rust 2021 edition).